# RegisterTemplate type error - C# .Net Handlebars

Tags: c#, type-conversion, handlebars.net

The [docs](https://github.com/rexm/Handlebars.Net) for this library seem straightforward enough, but attempting to register a partial throws a type conversion error:

```
string testname = "myName";
string testbody = @"my really simple test body";
Handlebars.RegisterTemplate(testname, testbody);
```

`Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Action<System.IO.TextWriter, object>'`

Somewhat new to C# still, but this is almost identical to the example in the docs so I can't imagine that I've somehow miss-typed the `testbody` string.

**Further research**

Literally copy-pasting the example breaks the code. Looks like this may just be a crap library.

```
string partialSource = 
@"<strong>{{name}}</strong>";

Handlebars.RegisterTemplate("user", partialSource);
```

`Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Action<System.IO.TextWriter, object>'`

Comment: How certain are you that you're using the right version? `RegisterTemplate(string, string)` seems to exist: https://github.com/rexm/Handlebars.Net/blob/master/source/Handlebars/Handlebars.cs#L37 (Looks like it was only added on January 31st though)

Comment: Ah, and last NuGet package was from October 2016. You might want to ask on GitHub when they're planning on releasing a new version.

Comment: @JonSkeet any suggestions/resources on how to use this without NuGet?

Comment: Fetch from GitHub, build it yourself.

Comment: @JonSkeet This is probably answer-worthy if you want to post it as such

Comment: @JonSkeet not that I can anyways... because it requires a version newer than 2015 to open, and I don't have that available. Oh well, was worth a shot.

Comment: You could install the .NET Core SDK 1.0.3 and build with that, then use the package from VS2015.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The static `Handlebars.RegisterTemplate(string, string)` method was added in [this commit](https://github.com/rexm/Handlebars.Net/commit/8a9dd19fb5fad894a13419481fc198e6bd4f94a4) on January 31st 2017. The last NuGet release of [`Handlebars.Net`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Handlebars.Net/) was in October 2016 - so you don't have access to it yet.

Options:

- Wait for it to be released on NuGet
- Download and build locally from GitHub
- Effectively work round it by doing what the new code does.

For the final option, I believe you should be able to replace this:

```
string testName = "myName";
string testBody = @"my really simple test body";
Handlebars.RegisterTemplate(testName, testBody);
```

with

```
var template = Handlebars.Compile(new StringReader(testBody));
Handlebars.Register(testName, template);
```